# logcat won't clear out for multiple devices

Tags: android, testing, adb, android-logcat

I can't get the logcat to clear out it worked when i had just one device running but when i have two it doesn't work.  I'm running the script every 5 mins and want the log to be cleared so the log file created is for that particular test run each time.

`logcat -c` is the command to clear it but it doesn't seem to be working

any ideas?

```
cd C:\Users\nicho\android-sdks\platform-tools
adb
adb -s emulator-5554 shell logcat -c
adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w com.example.nicho.pleasework.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
set timestamp=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
adb -s emulator-5554 logcat -d -v time MyTest:I > "C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\logs\robotium\%timestamp%-Robotium_Em_logcat.txt"
adb -s emulator-5554 shell logcat -c
adb -s emulator-5556 shell logcat -c
adb -s emulator-5556 shell am instrument -w com.example.nicho.pleasework.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
set timestamp=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
adb -s emulator-5556 logcat -d -v time MyTest:I > "C:\Users\nicho\Desktop\logs\nexus4\%timestamp%-Nexus_4_logcat.txt"
adb -s emulator-5556 shell logcat -c
```

Comment: I've also tried without the `shell` command in that place as well

Comment: Have you tried to open the device `shell` first, and only once you're there you do the `logcat -c`?

Comment: I'm running the script from a .bat file.  whenever i send the command to just open the shell the script stops and won't send anymore commands after that.                                                                                                                      i didn't have the problem when it was just one device.  It is actually working on the first device now but not on the second makes no sense

Comment: What if you try to do that using Windows `cmd.exe`? Perhaps that will work. But now I think I get it, you want to clear them all using a script, right? You should edit your question with that info. ;)